# Run subprocess.popen with N arguments

Tags: python, subprocess, dynamic-programming, popen

subprocess.popen invokes process in background.

I am invoking php process and sometimes python process, and every time arguments may be different. I want to write one function and in that I will pass list of arguments. And that function will execute process based on the arguments.

So what I am doing is, written below and it was bad way actually and I don't want to write so many lines.

```
    def RunBackGroundProcess(args):
        # args is an array of params
        # index 0 - command - php/python or anyother
        # index 1 - filename - that you want to run. Specify fullpath if required
        # index 2 - param_1
        # index 3 - param_2
        # index N - param_N

        if(len(args) == 2):
            subprocess.Popen([args[0], args[1], args[2]])

        if(len(args) == 3):
            subprocess.Popen([args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]])

        if(len(args) == 4):
            subprocess.Popen([args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4]])
```

What about if I have 10 arguments or 15 arguments? This is bad way, right?
Help me to write this code in smaller lines.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(list(args))`?

Comment: @mgilson is wrapping it with `list` necessary?  I assume it is already a list (though it does say array that seems unlikely)

Comment: @sberry -- It depends on the inputs and how paranoid/flexible you want the interface to be... If the inputs are always required to be a `sequence`, then no, you absolutely don't need to wrap it in `list`.  With that said, it doesn't really hurt if you're trying to write something frameworky and therefore you want to also accept arbitrary iterables (I assume you aren't passing generators that yield enough elements to be problematic to `subprocess`)...

Comment: Is `args` already the right size? Why not just `Popen(args)`?

Comment: Or potentially use shell=True and pass in a string rather than a list....subprocess. Popen('my_script.py param1 param2', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

Comment: @mgilson subprocess.Popen(args) worked. No need to wrap with list. args is always a list. I wrote array cause I learned c in old school and so, that word came first.

Comment: @wom it is not possible in my case, cause number of arguments are not predefined.

Comment: @mgilson What do you mean by passing generators. Actually I don't know what is generator?

Comment: Re: indeterminate number of args beign an issue - subprocess. Popen('my_script.py {}'.format(' '.join([str(x) for x in args])), shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)    Not saying  this is the best method; just an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing args as list, So while subprocess.Popen() no need to check argument length you can just pass as it is to subprocess

```
def RunBackGroundProcess(args):
    subprocess.Popen(args)
```

This will work